# Add a link wrapping an TYPO3 fluid image

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have an fluid code for mask extension:

```
<f:image image="{file}" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}"  class="img-fullwidth" />
```

I want to wrap that code with a tag with href to the same image file, so finally I will have `<a href="image-file-source"><img src="image-file-source" /></a>"`

Is that even possible with fluid ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This working for me

```
<a href="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}">
    {file.originalResource.title}
</a>
```

In your example

```
<a href="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}">
    <f:image image="{file}" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}" class="img-fullwidth" />
</a>"
```

Comment: This solution does not respect `config.absRefPrefix` if TYPO3 is installed in a sub-folder

Comment: Thank you Heinz, your solution currently works good. I hope that it still working when i deploy to live server.

Answer (score 3):

Try to something like this

```
 <f:link.typolink parameter="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}">
      <f:image image="{file}" alt="{file.alternative}" title="{file.title}" class="img-fullwidth" />
</f:link.typolink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the link.typolink viewhelper like this:

```
<f:for each="{data.image}" as="file">
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{file.link}">
        <f:image image="{file}" />
    </f:link.typolink>
</f:for>
```